# Background music style of cops movies

Tags: identify-this-genre

Don't really know how to describe it, but I'm looking for the name of style/type of background music used in "funny" cop movies/series. I need the name of it so I can do research and look at different songs for a video-editing project.

Let's say, like the one used in the first seconds of this video for example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3CwWyPwEu4

Or this one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O09tBUlLtbI

Comment: Do you have an example where we can hear it better?

Comment: Tried to add another example, but it is difficult as it is mainly backgrouund music everytime. (Sorry for putting B99 again, but that's the most recent example I can remember of...)

Comment: Is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAFEMy9SrfY) a better example of what you're looking for?

Comment: @ChrisSunami Probably not, this looks more like an action/chasing scene. I'm rather looking for dialog/trivial thing scene. AAaaah this is bugging me so much to not be able to precisely point at something

Comment: you may want to look at the answers to this question: chances are it may be among them.  https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/6419/identify-soundtrack-for-funny-fast-motion-runs-or-chases-in-comedy

Comment: @Angst No, sorry. Again, I'm not looking for action/chasing scene.

Answer (score 2):

I'll defer to the previous responders on this, but to me this style is almost a pastiche of the [Gotcha theme by Tom Scott](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FcjIKLH_TpU). AMG lists a number of [styles that Scott is known for](https://www.allmusic.com/artist/tom-scott-mn0000934350/songs); the best I can come up with is Sax Jazz-Funk.

Also, how would we describe the Lalo Schifrin soundtracks of "Bullit" or "Dirty Harry"?. The tv soundtracks are almost a modern take on these styles, albeit with a lighter feel.